# Hot to prove this proposition?

Tags: integers

$n \in N$ is positive integer, and $64^n-7^n$ can be divisible by 57. Prove that $8^{2n+1}+7^{n+2}$ is also divisible by 57.

Comment: it is gg if you have not tried

Comment: I have tried to change the form of $8^{2n}+7^{n+2}$ to have relation to $64^n-7^n$ and I also have tried with Mathematical induction, but I failed.

Comment: @jiadong If you know congruences (modular aritmetic) then it is best to view it simply as the multiplication of two congruences - see my answer. It is essential to learn congruences in order to master elementary number theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

$$8^{2n+1}+7^{n+2} = 8\cdot 64^n + 49\cdot 7^n =8\cdot 64^n + (57-8)\cdot 7^n =\color{blue}{ 8(64^n-7^n) + 57\cdot 7^n} $$

Comment: Thank you! I failed since I wanted to change  $64^n$ to $8^{2n}$ and did not relate 49 to 57.

Comment: Thanks, It is helpful. I have changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually it's just congruence $\rm\color{#c00}{multiplication}$ using $\,\color{#0a0}{\rm CPR} =\,$ [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

$$\begin{array}{rrl}{\rm mod}\,\ 57\!:\!\!\!\! 
& -8\!\!\!\!&\equiv\, 49\\
&64^n\!\!\!\!&\equiv\, 7^n\\
\color{#c00}\Rightarrow &-8\cdot 64^n\!\!\!\!&\equiv\, 49\cdot 7^n\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#0a0}{\rm CPR}\\
{\rm i.e.}  &\,-8^{2n+1}\!\!\!\!&\equiv\, 7^{n+2}\end{array}\qquad\qquad$$

The proof is ganeshie8's answer is precisely the proof of CPR specialized to these numbers.

**Remark** $\ $ Similarly $\ 64\equiv 7\,\Rightarrow\, 64^n\equiv 7^n\,$ is an instance of the [Congruence Power Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) which is simply an inductive extension of the Product Rule.

Comment: Thanks!! Having the CPR in mind, I feel that it is much more natural to find a way to prove this problem!

Comment: @jiadong Yes, congruence arithmetic allows us to convert many divisibility problems into trivial congruence arithmetic (which, being so similar to integer arithmetic, allows us to reuse our grade-school intuition, which is lacking for arithmetic of divisibility relations).